# My post has been changed. What to do if I don't like it?

Tags: support, editing

Meistens ist es optisch besser. Was mache ich aber ,  wenn meine Antwort sachlich geändert wurde und mir das nicht gefällt?
Und was ist ein "rollback"?

---

It sometimes looks better. But, what should I do, if my answer has been changed in subsance, and I don't like that change?
And, what's a "rollback"?

Answer (score 4):

Rollbacks sind genau für den Fall vorgesehen, dass Du denkst, dass ein Beitrag unangemessen geändert wurde:

- Klicke auf *edited X ago.*
- Suche beste Version.
- Klicke auf *rollback* in der zugehörigen Kopfleiste.
- Der Beitrag wird dann auf die entsprechende Version zurückgesetzt.

Wenn die fragliche Änderung sowohl positiv als auch negativ war, kann es jedoch sinnvoller sein, nur die negativen Änderungen rückgängig zu machen (per Hand).

Generell ist es absolut legitim, wenn Du zu tiefgreifende Änderungen auf die eine oder andere Weise rückgängig machst. Im *Review-Edits-*Dialog (wo Nutzer mit hoher Erfahrung Änderungen kontrollieren, die von Nutzern mit geringer Erfahrung vorgeschlagen wurden) ist dies einer der Ablehnungsgründe.

---

Rollbacks are exactly for this case where you think that a post has been edited inappropriately:

- Click on *edited X ago.*
- Choose the best version.
- Click on *rollback* in the corresponding header.
- The corresponding version is now once more the current version of the post.

If the edit had both, positive and negative aspects, you might however consider to only revert the negative changes (manually).

In general there is nothing wrong about reverting edits that change the nature of the post. Actually, this is one of the rejection options in the *review edits* dialogue (where high-reputation users can review edits suggested by low-reputation users).

Comment: Thanks for the information.